# Show SQLite data in Custom ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview

I am trying to show data from `SQLite` into a custom `ListView`. I got the data and I can show it into `ListView`, But I have a problem.

Everytime I scroll it into the last data in `ListView` its always error. Its said ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I already search it but still can't find the solution.

So what I want to ask is, how to fix that error or is there another method that I can use to show the data in `ListView`?

Here's My **DatabaseHandler.java**

```
// Getting All search result
public List<AllItem> getAllSearchResult(String searchResult) {
    List<AllItem> allsearchResultList = new ArrayList<AllItem>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ALLITEM + " WHERE " + KEY_ITEM_NAME_ALLITEM +  " LIKE '%"+searchResult+"%' ";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            AllItem allitem = new AllItem();
            allitem.setTableID(cursor.getInt(0));
            allitem.setID(cursor.getString(1));
            allitem.setCategory_name(cursor.getString(2));
            allitem.setItem_Name(cursor.getString(3));

            allitem.setDescription(cursor.getString(4));
            allitem.setAddress(cursor.getString(5));
            allitem.setArea (cursor.getString(6));
            allitem.setAreaName (cursor.getString(7));

            // Adding searchResult to list
            allsearchResultList.add(allitem);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return searchResult list
    return allsearchResultList;
}
```

Here's My **Search.java**

```
    Intent search = getIntent();
    String searchResult = search.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    //Cursor mCur = (Cursor) db.getAllSearchResults(searchResult); 

    //CurAdapter Cur = new CurAdapter(Search.this, mCur,0); 
    //final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listSearch); 
    //lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    //lv.setAdapter(Cur);

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts.."); 
    List <AllItem> allItems = new ArrayList<AllItem>();


    allItems = db.getAllSearchResult(searchResult);


    ArrayList <String> allItems2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (AllItem cn : allItems) {
        allItems2.add(cn.getItem_name());
        allItems2.add(cn.getAreaNAme());
        allItems2.add(cn.getCategory_name());
    }


    CustomAdapterSearch adapter = new CustomAdapterSearch(Search.this, allItems2);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And here's my **CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapterSearch extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final List<String> items;

public CustomAdapterSearch (Activity context, List<String> items) {

    super(context, R.layout.searchlayout, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView (final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchlayout, null, true);

    TextView itemName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    TextView areaName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.area_name);
    TextView priceCatergory = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.price_category);

    itemName.setText(items.get(3*position));
    areaName.setText(items.get(3*position + 1));
    priceCatergory.setText(items.get(3*position + 2));

    return rowView;

}
```

}

Is there anyone can help me? Thanks before :D

Comment: this must have something to do with this piece of Your code: items.get(3*position). What´s Your intention for this?

Comment: use SimpleCursorAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter

Comment: Its for the position and how much column i use for it.

Comment: @pskink can you give me an example? or good tutorial for that?

Comment: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Answer (score 0):

**Search.java**

```
 Intent search = getIntent();
    String searchResult = search.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);


    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts.."); 
    List <AllItem> allItems = new ArrayList<AllItem>();


    allItems = db.getAllSearchResult(searchResult);

    CustomAdapterSearch adapter = new CustomAdapterSearch(Search.this, allItems);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);



public class CustomAdapterSearch extends ArrayAdapter<AllItem> {

private final Activity context;
private final List<AllItem> items;

public CustomAdapterSearch (Activity context, List<AllItem> items) {

    super(context, R.layout.searchlayout, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView (final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchlayout, null, true);

    TextView itemName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    TextView areaName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.area_name);
    TextView priceCatergory = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.price_category);

    itemName.setText(items.get(position)); // there must be property of class AllItem add them after get method
    areaName.setText(items.get(position));
    priceCatergory.setText(items.get(position));

    return rowView;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I got an error on areaName.setText(items.get(position));  said `the method setText (CharSequence) in the typoe is not applicable for the argument (allItem)

Comment: i told u  there must be property of class AllItem add them after get method to all

Answer (score 0):

you are doing wrong when convert Cursor to AllItem

use CursorAdapter and Filtrable interface to filter results

Comment: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html  this sample looks little bit superfluous, but is's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Search.java** recommended by *Android Genius*

```
Intent search = getIntent();
String searchResult = search.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

/**
 * CRUD Operations
 * */
Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts.."); 
List <AllItem> allItems = new ArrayList<AllItem>();

allItems = db.getAllSearchResult(searchResult);

CustomAdapterSearch adapter = new CustomAdapterSearch(Search.this, allItems);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now use *AllItem* class passed into **CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapterSearch extends ArrayAdapter<AllItem> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final List<AllItem> items;

    public CustomAdapterSearch (Activity context, List<AllItem> items) {

        super(context, R.layout.searchlayout, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchlayout, null, true);

        TextView itemName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        TextView areaName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.area_name);
        TextView priceCatergory = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.price_category);

        itemName.setText(items.get(position).getItem_name());
        areaName.setText(items.get(position).getAreaNAme());
        priceCatergory.setText(items.get(position).getCategory_name());

       return rowView;

    }
}
```